# Hoe to removeAll on Ext.query('.classname')-EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to remove all the elements from the array using:

```
Ext.query('.classname') // gets me array of elements
```

the `Ext.query('.classname').removeall()` is not a function it supports, how to achieve this?

thanks

Comment: could you provide some more details; for example, what are these "elements" ?

Comment: the elements are array of `divs`: elements = [<div>...</div><div>....</div>] something like this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

guess it should be something alike this:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel[cls=classname]').each(function(cmp) {
    cmp.destroy();
});
```

`Ext.query` is actually `Ext.dom.query`, therefore it will not return the component

... alike [Ext.ComponentQuery](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/Ext.ComponentQuery.html) does.

**explanation**: the question does not indicate against what the code shall run; therefore I'd assume it to be ExtJS components - and not the HTML content within a ExtJS panel (which would have no representation within the framework). the point is, that when removing DOM nodes, without destroying the associated components, this will leave orphaned references behind. therefore destroying them properly is suggested, so that those won't needlessly occupy RAM anymore, eg. in case removing DOM nodes and then adding new ExtJS components, over and over again - this would lead to sluggish behavior.

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about components.

Comment: @OP, if this is the correct answer to your question, you need to update your question.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Ext.select`, which wraps the return elements so that you can call `Ext.dom.Element` methods as though they were a group:

```
Ext.select('.even').remove();
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2l47).

Comment: down-voted, because DOM manipulation is pointless in ExtJS (leaving broken references).

Comment: That's just flat out wrong. Even if that was the case, it's what the question is asking for.

Comment: added a more detailed explanation "why", which could be easily reproduced in a stress test; that the op does not indicate against what the code runs, indicates that he might not have considered it. both answers may be correct - but it depends on the given situation.

Comment: What you wrote is correct, typically you shouldn't go messing with the internal DOM of a component. However that's not what the OP is asking and your assertion that "DOM manipulation is pointless" is, at best, a shallow viewpoint. How do you think you put together a custom component?